# How can I use two-finger swipe to switch windows?

Tags: touchpad, macbook, multi-touch, touchegg

I'd basically like the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination to be performed whenever I swipe with two fingers left or right. I saw similar functionality in a Mac OS X and I think it might be useful =)

[TouchEgg wiki](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/Main?tm=6), however, doesn't seem to explain how one's supposed to set it up as to switch between windows with swiping, so... I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar but with a 3-figer swipe, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only two fingers may not work with all touchpads as most of the time the two fingers operations are hardcoded in the driver to perform vertical/horizontal scroll.